# Using own class in another Android Activity class

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have made this class:

```
public class DisplayItems extends ListActivity{

    ArrayList<String> contactNames = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> contactNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

    //Get the contacts in the phone
    public void getContacts(){
        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext())
        {
            String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            contactNumbers.add(phoneNumber);
            contactNames.add(name + "\n" + phoneNumber);
        }
        phones.close();
    }

    //displaying contacts name and numbers in a listView
    public void displayContacts(){
        ListView lstView = getListView();
        lstView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, contactNames));
    }
}
```

Now I want to use that class in this one:

```
public class PickNumbersActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pick_numbers);

        //Get message text
        Intent i = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
        String message_text = extras.getString("message");

        DisplayItems display = new DisplayItems();
        display.getContacts();
        display.displayContacts();

    }
}
```

But it's not working... and I'm new to android studio and I don't even know where to look for error messages when my app doesn't work
Thanks.

Comment: If you are using Android Studio, there should be a tab at the bottom that says "logcat". Click on that in order to get the error messages. Also, it should automatically pop up when you run your application.

Comment: Add your own log debug points as well. May help

Comment: Click on "DisplayItems" (it should be underlined in red if it's not loading) and press Alt + Enter to import the class. You cannot reference classes without statically importing them.

Comment: Why you want to include an Activity into another one? That sounds like a bad design.

Comment: Thanks IntegralOfTan i found it...

Comment: i want to include it because if i don't extend the ActionBarActivity it won't show me the action bar for that activity... is there another way to solve that problem so that i can extend ListActivity and still get the action bar to be visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you're trying to instantiate your `DisplayItems` class which extends `ListActivity` and you shouldn't be using it like that. A better method would be to turn `DisplayItems` into `DisplayItemsFragment` like so.

First of all make sure you have a layout with an id of `container`.

Then add this to your `PickNumbersActivity`:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new DisplayItemsFragment())
            .commit();
}
```

Finally make your class extend ListFragment like so:

```
public class DisplayItemsFragment extends ListFragment{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getContacts();

    }

    //Get the contacts in the phone
    public void getContacts(){
        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext())
        {
            String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            contactNumbers.add(phoneNumber);
            contactNames.add(name + "\n" + phoneNumber);
        }
        phones.close();
        displayContacts();
    }

    //displaying contacts name and numbers in a listView
    public void displayContacts(){
        ListView lstView = getListView();
        lstView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, contactNames));
    }
}
```

If you have more questions just checkout the official [working with fragments documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Comment: Glad to know, if this question helped then you might want to accept it by checking the checkmark next to it.